# What to do with debugging questions when fixing one problem exposes another? Should a separate question be asked?

Tags: discussion

Concrete example:

- [Sending E-mail Hotmail Account via Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752741/4279)
- [Sending Email with Python (Raspbian OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752957/4279)

Despite almost identical titles (and the same user task -- send email) the questions are about different issues underneath: the first question might be about shadowing Python stdlib module due to filename conflict. The second -- about ssl error.

Should such questions be merged (one closed as a duplicate of another) or should they be kept separate?

Comment: Keep them seperate IMO

Comment: If the issues are different, the titles should be too.

Answer (score 2):

- if issues are different enough and they make sense as different questions then they should be separate questions
- titles should be changed to reflect the actual questions