# What should I do when I want to add additional questions or scenario to my question?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions

For example, let's say I've asked a question like this: `"If I've broken my arms, what should I do?"`

Someone answered `"If you have money, you may go to the clinic."`

In fact, the answer-er have already fulfilled my needs in real-world case. However, I may curious for something and would like to ask more.

Question 1: Since the answer-er answered the question with precondition `"If you have money"`. So I would like to ask `"What if I don't have money"`. What should I do? I may comment and waiting for this reply, but I would like to have an official way.

Question 2: In my question, I've also give my precondition `"If I've broken my arms"`. I may want to know if the answer applies in different scenario, like `"If I've broken my legs"`. What should I do? Should I create another question and edit my question?

Actually I've got these questions when I ask another question in StackOverflow, FYI [My original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760780/what-to-do-if-classes-with-same-interface-having-similar-but-different-method-si)

Comment: Create another question, you can always refer in that to the original question if you need to. Search first to check your new question has not already been asked and answered though.

Comment: Don't ask hypothetical questions.

Comment: @DeerHunter It doesn't matter when I ask "If I've broken my arms, what should I do?" or "I've broken my arms, what should I do?". Every question have its own assumption and answers as based on one set of assumptions. The problem is when an assumption is slightly changed, should I create another question

Comment: @RobertLongson Perfectly ok if I create another questions if there is slight change. Just wanna align with StackExchange standard.

Comment: @gnat I normally agree with your excellent duplicate finding skills and close vote but isn't this question the exact opposite of the dupe?

Comment: @rene although opposite, it seemed "too exact" so I couldn't resist. If it was not that close, I'd probably pick something like [Answer to question reveals 'new' bug => New question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134785/165773) or [What to do with debugging questions when fixing one problem exposes another? Should a separate question be asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213463/165773)